# JQuery - How can I determine if a specific class has been Toggled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="tab1"><div>

<div class="tab1 active"></div>
```

Given the code above how can I tell using jQuery that the tab1 class has been changed or 'made active'

One solution I think there is a better version of is adding a id to the tab1 div and checking if the class has 'active' appended on it.

[psuedocode below]

```
$('#tab1').click(function() {
   var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
   if(myClass.stringAt(6-12) == active){
       // do something
   }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `hasClass()` to check whether it has the `class` `active`. Also note that in your code `tab1` is a class and not ID so it should be

```
$('.tab1').click(function() {//Note that tab1 is a class in your code
  if($(this).hasClass('active')){// Check if the div has the class active or not
   //Do your operation
  })
})
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `tab1` is a class, not an ID in his HTML. It should be using `$('.tab1')` instead of the `#` selector.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to use :visible and :hidden via the [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function which can be seen in use below, please note that I wrote it as a unit test so you can, by yourself, test different scenarios and learn from them. Hope it helps!

HTML

```
<div class="tab1"></div>

<div class="tab1 active"></div>
```

jQuery 2.1.3

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){                       
    if(jQuery(".tab1").is(":visible")){
        alert("tab1 is visible");
    }
    else{
        alert("nothing is :visible");
    }
    if(jQuery(".tab1.active").is(":visible")){
        alert("tab1 active is visible");
    }
    else{
        alert("nothing is :visible");
    }
});
```

Take a look here for a 'visual' example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/ox9c02o8/)

jQuery reference: [Determining the state of a toggled element](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-determine-the-state-of-a-toggled-element/)